# Does fakeAsync guarantee promise completion after tick/flushMicroservice

Tags: angular

Main issue is how to test that expected actions were performed once a Promise was completed, for example to test if a component correctly updates its states after receiving some remote content.

In the specs below, the `dealWithIt()` simulates a logic performed in response to a completed promise (it updates variable and trigger "another async event").

```
it('Promises fulfilled by flushMicrotasks',fakeAsync((): void => {

    let x = 1;
    let y = 2;

    let dealWithIt = function(p:Promise<number>) {
        p.then( v => {
            x = v;
            Promise.resolve(v).then( v=> {y = v+1; });
        });
    };

    let p = Promise.resolve(y);

    dealWithIt(p);

    flushMicrotasks();
    //valid if promise handling completed
    expect(x).toBe(2);
    expect(y).toBe(3);


}));

it('Promises fulfilled by tick',fakeAsync((): void => {
    let x = 1;
    let y = 2;

    let dealWithIt = function(p:Promise<number>) {
        p.then( v => {
            x = v;
            Promise.resolve(v).then( v=> {y = v+1; });
        });
    };

    let p = Promise.resolve(y);

    dealWithIt(p);

    tick();
    //valid if promise handling completed

    expect(x).toBe(2);
    expect(y).toBe(3);

}));
```

And both tests pass. At the time of checking expectations the promise was dealt with correctly.

But, **is it guaranteed**? Or was I just lucky.

Are there any limitations, will all Promises created in the scope of fakeAsync be 'fired' by calling `tick` or `flushMicrotasks`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using together `fakeAsync` and `tick` / `flushMicrotasks` allows you to simulate asynchronous processing but in a "synchronous" way. So it's guaranteed that the callback you specified in your `then` method is executed before executed your expectations.

From the documentation:

- **fakeAsync**

> Wraps a function to be executed in the fakeAsync zone:
>
> - microtasks are manually executed by calling flushMicrotasks(),
> - timers are synchronous, tick() simulates the asynchronous passage of time.
>
> If there are any pending timers at the end of the function, an exception will be thrown.

- **tick**

> **export tick(millis?: number) : void**
>
> exported from angular2/testing defined in angular2/src/testing/fake_async.ts (line 84)
>   Simulates the asynchronous passage of time for the timers in the fakeAsync zone.
>
> The microtasks queue is drained at the very start of this function and after any timer callback has been executed.

- **flushMicrotasks**

> **export flushMicrotasks() : void**
>
> Flush any pending microtasks.

Here is the corresponding plunkr:

- https://plnkr.co/edit/ARGGaY?p=preview

**Under the hood**

In fact the `fakeAsync` function creates a dedicated zone that intercepts asynchronous processing of functions `setTimeout`, `clearTimeout`, `setInterval`, `clearInterval` but also override the `scheduleMicrotask` function. This way the `fakeAsync` can completely control asynchronous processing and simulate asynchronous processing. It relies on the `DelayedFunctionScheduler` from Jasmine.

Registering a callback on a promise using the `then` method immediately queues a microtask by calling the `scheduleMicrotask` function previously defined in the custom zone. This way this zone has the hand on when to execute the promise callback.

The `flushMicrotasks` function simply iterates over the registered microtasks and execute them synchronously (included the previously registered callback of the promise). The `tick` does the same but calls in addition the `tick` method of the Jasmine scheduler.

This article could give more details:

- https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

You could have a look at the source code of the `fakeAsync`:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/testing/fake_async.ts#L34

Comment: Hi, I saw the docs but it does not say anything about promises only misterious microtasks. Are Microtasks == Promise. I tried to find what the microtasks are meant to be but I could not.

Comment: In fact, when defining the callback of the promise using its `then` method, a microtask is scheduled under the hood. I updated my answer to explain this ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to test this without using Angular's bloated helpers? I want to write a simple test and run it using `tape` or something similar. Is there a way I can just return a promise from my test and have the test framework verify that it did not reject (e.g. using `async/await`) so that I can avoid all this coupling and statefulness when writing tests that have nothing to do with the framework (service tests that contain business logic, not rendering)?

Answer (score 3):

So yes, as Thierry explained in his answer fakeAsync allows testing synchronously the business logic behind handling promises.

I just wanted to add, that the test for fakeAsync have even specs for promise related scenarios:

```
describe('Promise', () => {
      it('should run asynchronous code', fakeAsync(() => {
...
      it('should run chained thens', fakeAsync(() => {
...
      it('should run Promise created in Promise', fakeAsync(() => {
```

I found those tests at: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/test/fake_async_spec.ts

Comment: Link is out of date.