# Jasmine: testing observables with events

Tags: javascript, testing, typescript, jasmine, angular

I am trying to test an angular2 application. I have a login form, which uses an observable to send data to the backend:

```
doLogin() {
    this.usersService.login(this.model)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log("In observable: " + data.isSuccess);
            if (!data.isSuccess) {
                this.alerts.push({});
            }
        });
}
```

In tests I am adding a spy on the service function, which returns observable, so that component can work on it:

```
 usersService.login.and.returnValue(Observable.of(
    <LoginResponse>{
        isSuccess: true
    }));
```

When everything is ready, I dispatch an event on submit button, which triggers doLogin function in component:

```
submitButton.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
fixture.detectChanges();
```

It works correctly. Unfortunately, when I check if usersService.login has been called in the test:

```
expect(usersService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I get an error, because the observable didn't finish and login has not been called yet.

How should I make sure, I check my spy after observable has finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you configure the service on the component but it works for me when I override providers of the component created from `TestComponentBuilder`.

Let's take a sample. I have a service that returns a list of string:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class MyService {
  getDogs() {
    return Observable.of([ 's1', 's2', ... ]);
  }
}
```

A component uses this service to display a list asynchronously when clicking a button:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  providers: [MyService],
  template: `
    <ul><li *ngFor="#item of items">{{ item }}</li></ul>
    <div id="test" (click)="test()">Test</div>
  `
})
export class MyList implements OnInit {
  items:Array<string>;
  service:MyService;

  constructor(private service:MyService) {
  }

  test() {
    this.service.getDogs().subscribe(
      (dogs) => {
        this.items = dogs;
      });
  }
}
```

I want to test that when I click on the "Test" button, the `test` method of the component is called and the `getDogs` method of the service is indirectly called.

For this, I create a test that instantiate directly the service and load the component using `TestComponentBuilder`. In this case, I need to call the `overrideProviders` method on it before calling `createAsync`. This way, you will be able to provide your spied service to be notified of the call. Here is a sample:

```
let service:MyService = new MyService();

beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(service, 'getDogs').and.returnValue(Observable.of(
        ['dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3']));

});

it('should test get dogs', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    return tcb.overrideProviders(MyList, [provide(MyService, { useValue: service })])
              .createAsync(MyList).then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture) => {
        const element = componentFixture.nativeElement;
        componentFixture.detectChanges();

        var clickButton = document.getElementById('test');
        clickButton.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));

        expect(service.getDogs).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
}));
```

**Edit**

Since the event is triggered asynchronously, you could consider to use `fakeAsync`. The latter allows you to completly control when asynchronous processing are handled and turn asynchronous things in to synchronous ones.

You could wrap your test processing into

```
fakeAsync((): void => {
  var clickButton = document.getElementById('test');
  clickButton.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));

  expect(service.getDogs).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

For more details, you could have a look at this question:

- [Does fakeAsync guarantee promise completion after tick/flushMicroservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990253/does-fakeasync-guarantee-promise-completion-after-tick-flushmicroservice)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I do it in the same way but in my case, toHaveBeenCalled is being checked before service method is invoked by component.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand ;-) The component invokes the service synchronously and the service method executes something asynchronous and returns an observable. Right?

Comment: yes, that's right, but as I understand it, dispatchEvent is asynchronous, so the test() function is called in async mode and expect might be checked before getDogs is invoked.

Comment: How do you execute your test? With Karma?

Comment: That said if you want to wait for the observable receives data, you could consider to use `fakeAsync`. The latter allows you to completly control when asynchronous processing are handled and turn asynchronous things in to synchronous ones ;-) This question should interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990253/does-fakeasync-guarantee-promise-completion-after-tick-flushmicroservice/35991133#35991133.