# Angular2 http call make tests execute twice

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, angular

I have a Angular2 app with a simple component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Techs',
  template: '',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class Techs {
  public techs: Tech[];

  constructor(http: Http) {
    http
      .get('src/app/techs/techs.json')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(result => this.techs = result);
  }
}
```

My tests are executed twice:

> Chrome 49.0.2623 (Mac OS X 10.11.4): Executed 0 of 6 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>
> LOG: 'end of test'
>
> Chrome 49.0.2623 (Mac OS X 10.11.4): Executed 6 of 6 SUCCESS (0.182 secs / 0.153 secs)

However if I remove the Http call the test is only executed once

> Chrome 49.0.2623 (Mac OS X 10.11.4): Executed 6 of 6 SUCCESS (0.182 secs / 0.153 secs)

Here is my test

```
describe('techs component', () => {
  it('should render 3 elements <tech>', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    return tcb
      .createAsync(Techs)
      .then(fixture => {
        fixture.componentInstance.techs = [{}, {}, {}];
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const techs = fixture.nativeElement;
        expect(techs.querySelectorAll('tech').length).toBe(3);
      });
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem comes from the asynchronous aspect of your HTTP call. I would see two ways to fix this:

- Another way would be to **mock your Http object** into order to simulate the HTTP call. This can be done using the `MockBackend` class.

Here is to configure it against the `XHRBackend` class:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => {
  return [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: MockBackend }),
 ];
});
```

and a way to return what you want in the response:

```
it('Should return a list of dogs', inject([XHRBackend, HttpService, Injector], (mockBackend, httpService, injector) => {
  mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
    (connection: MockConnection) => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(
        new ResponseOptions({
          body: [ { name: 'test' }, ... ]
      })));
    }
    (...)
```

- Perhaps something you could be using the **fake async support of Angular2**. This way you will be able to control asynchronous processing in a synchronous way... See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/testing/fakeAsync-function.html.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried to mock the Http request but still the same... About `fakeAsync`, should I use it combined with the first method (mocking Http backend) ?

Comment: You could try with both. FakeAsync allows you to manually trigger microtasks. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990253/does-fakeasync-guarantee-promise-completion-after-tick-flushmicroservice/35991133?s=0|2.5647#35991133

Comment: Otherwise how do you run your test?

Comment: I'm using Karma. The thing is that I cannot use `fakeAsync` because `TestComponentBuilder.createAsync` is async and returns a promise...

Comment: By the way, I noticed that if I move the http call in a method `initData()` and then, from my test, I override this method as in `Techs.prototype.initData = function(){...}`, then it works (probably because asynchronous http call is not done anymore)