# Testing basic navigation in Angular 2 with fakeAsync() instead of Jasmine's done()

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, angular2-routing, gherkin

I currently have a working test using Gherkin steps and Jasmine async done() for basic navigation as such:

```
User_Navigates_To_URL(urlPath: string) {
    return this.router.navigateByUrl(urlPath);
}

User_Will_Be_On_URL(expectedPath: string) {
    expect(this.location.path()).toBe(expectedPath);
}

it('Scenario: User should be able to navigate', (done) => {
    When.User_Navigates_To_URL('/associates/your-team').then(() => {
        Then.User_Will_Be_On_URL('/associates/your-team');
    });
    done();
});
```

But what I'm trying to accomplish is to write this test using [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/fakeAsync-function.html) instead of jasmine's done() method. This way all async actions will be resolved in the zone and I wont have to nest the assertion step as a callback of the promise. Therefore, I'm attempting to do something like so:

```
it('Scenario: User should be able to navigate', <any>fakeAsync(() => {
    When.User_Navigates_To_URL('/associates/your-team');
    tick();
    Then.User_Will_Be_On_URL('/associates/your-team');
}));
```

After weeks of research, the only thing close I found helpful was this question: [Does fakeAsync guarantee promise completion after tick/flushMicroservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990253/does-fakeasync-guarantee-promise-completion-after-tick-flushmicroservice). But even when I've tried to implement my navigation promise in his snippet, it never resolves.

```
User_Navigates_To_URL(urlPath: string) {
    let currNav:Promise<Router> = this.router.navigateByUrl(urlPath);

    let handleNavigation = function (p:Promise<Router>) {
        p.then(() => {
            console.log('navigation complete')
        });
    };

    let p = Promise.resolve(currNav);

    handleNavigation(p);
    tick();
}
```

This is my first question on here so please let me know if my quesiton is confusing or if I need to provide any more details.