# Angular 2 fakeAsync waiting for timeout in a function using tick()?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, asynchronous, jasmine

I'm trying to get the results from a mock backend in Angular 2 for unit testing. Currently, we are using `fakeAsync` with a timeout to simulate the passing of time.

**current working unit test**

```
it('timeout (fakeAsync/tick)', fakeAsync(() => {
    counter.getTimeout();
    tick(3000); //manually specify the waiting time
}));
```

But, this means that we are limited to a manually defined timeout. Not when the async task is completed. What I'm trying to do is getting `tick()` to wait until the task is completed before continuing with the test.

This does not seem to work as intended.

Reading up on the `fakeAsync` and `tick` the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991133/3156644) explains that:

> tick() simulates the asynchronous passage of time.

I set up a [plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jm6T17qPbzM8abmRMckw?p=preview) simulating this scenario.

Here, we call the `getTimeout()` method which calls an internal async task that has a timeout. In the test, we try wrapping it and calling `tick()` after calling the `getTimeout()` method.

**counter.ts**

```
getTimeout() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout')
  },3000)
}
```

**counter.specs.ts**

```
it('timeout (fakeAsync/tick)', fakeAsync(() => {
    counter.getTimeout();
    tick();
}));
```

But, the unit test fails with the error "Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue."

Does the [issue here in the angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10127) have anything to do with this?

Is it possible to use `tick()` this way to wait for a timeout function? Or is there another approach that I can use?

Comment: I tried to solve this with a simple `async/await` helper. Unfortunately, while the tests pass and behave correctly, **zone.js** has a hissy fit, chokes and dies. One should be able to write a simple service test without all of this framework specific crap.

Comment: can anyone look in to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580184/how-can-i-do-unit-test-for-setinterval-in-ngoninit

Answer (score 47):

The purpose of `fakeAsync` is to control time within your spec. `tick` will not wait for any time as it is a synchronous function used to simulate the passage of time. If you want to wait until the asynchronous function is complete, you are going to need to use `async` and `whenStable`, however, in your example, the spec will take 3 seconds to pass so I wouldn't advise this.

The reason why the **counter.spec.ts** is failing is that you have only simulated the passage of 0 seconds (typically used to represent the next tick of the event loop). So when the spec completes, there are still mocked timers active and that fails the whole spec. It is actually working properly by informing you that a timeout has been mocked an is unhandled.

Basically, I think you are attempting to use `fakeAsync` and `tick` in ways for which they were not intended to be used. If you need to test a timeout the way that you have proposed, the simplest way would be to mock the `setTimeout` function yourself so that, regardless of the time used, you can just call the method.

**EDITED**
I ran into a related issue where I wanted to clear the timers, and since it was not the part under test, I didn't care how long it took. I tried:

```
tick(Infinity);
```

Which worked, but was super hacky. I ended up going with

```
discardPeriodicTasks();
```

And all of my timers were cleared.

Comment: Tried everything, but `discardPeriodicTasks()` worked perfect

Comment: Just to save time for who is here, `discardPeriodicTasks` is in `@angular/core/testing`

Answer (score 26):

Try to add one or a combination of the following function calls to the end of your test:

```
     flush();
     flushMicrotasks();
     discardPeriodicTasks();
```

or try to "kill" the pending tasks like this:

```
   Zone.current.get('FakeAsyncTestZoneSpec').pendingTimers = [];
   Zone.current.get('FakeAsyncTestZoneSpec').pendingPeriodicTimers = [];
```

1. `flush` (with optional maxTurns parameter) also flushes macrotasks. (This function is not mentionned in the Angular testing tutorial.)
2. `flushMicrotasks` flushes the microtask queue.
3. `discardPeriodicTasks` cancels "periodic timer(s) still in the queue".
4. Clearing the pending (periodic) timers array in the current fake async zone is a way to avoid the error if nothing else helps.

Timers in the queue do not necessarily mean that there's a problem with your code. For example, components that observe the current time may introduce such timers. If you use such components from a foreign library, you might also consider to stub them instead of "chasing timers".

For further understanding you may look at the javascript code of the `fakeAsync` function in `zone-testing.js`.

Comment: I had to use both flush() and disacrdPeriodicTasks() to do the trick. Wish I had some idea what the hell is going on but hey ho :-).

Comment: Just got the case that a superfluous fakeAsync around my test caused it to fail with a "timer still in the queue". Removing the fakeAsync fixed the test.

Comment: Sometimes a deep debugging session with the zone code can explain such a strange behaviour and reveal the pending tasks, but only if you have much time...

Comment: Using all of these, still 2 timers in the queue, if I remove fakeAsync, it runs without errors (but doesn't do what it's supposed to do, obviously).

Answer (score 16):

At the end of each test add:

```
 fixture.destroy();
 flush();
```

Comment: It bring waiting tasks from 3 to 1. But one still is in queue.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
// I had to do this:
it('timeout (fakeAsync/tick)', (done) => {
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
       counter.getTimeout();
       tick();
    done();
  });
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10127)

Answer (score 1):

**Async**

test.service.ts

```
export class TestService {
  getTimeout() {
    setTimeout(() => { console.log("test") }, 3000);
  }
}
```

test.service.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe("TestService", () => {
  let service: TestService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [TestService],
    });

    service = TestBed.get(TestService);
  });

  it("timeout test", async(() => {
    service.getTimeout();
  });
});
```

---

**Fake Async**

test.service.ts

```
export class TestService {
  readonly WAIT_TIME = 3000;

  getTimeout() {
    setTimeout(() => { console.log("test") }, this.WAIT_TIME);
  }
}
```

test.service.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe("TestService", () => {
  let service: TestService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [TestService],
    });

    service = TestBed.get(TestService);
  });

  it("timeout test", fakeAsync(() => {
    service.getTimeout();
    tick(service.WAIT_TIME + 10);
  });
});
```

Comment: Adding 10 millis is not necessary, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the flushMicrotasks method in my unit tests for use with my services. I had read that tick() is very similar to flushMicrotasks but also calls the jasmine tick() method.

Answer (score 0):

For me all above didnt helped, but a double call of `tick(<async_time>)` in my test code.

My explanation so far: for every async call you a need a single/own tick()-call.

I have a `.pipe(debounceTime(500))` and a `timer(500).subscribe(..)` afterwards and this helped:

```
tick(500);
tick(500);
```