# What is the difference between fakeAsync's tick() and done() in angular2 testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to figure out what differentiates fakeAsync's `tick()` method from `done()` as suggested by some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231191/8558515) on stack overflow.

Using `tick()` we can simulate a timeout, but can we accomplish the same using `done()`?

Why does angular consider it [more viable method](https://angular.io/guide/testing#jasminedone) than using `async` or `fakeAsync`?

Take for example.

This method works for me...

```
it("Should display names",(done:any) => {
        component.names = [
            {
                "firstname": "abc",
                "lastname": "max"
            },
            {
                "firstname": "def",
                "lastname": "max"
            },
        ];
        done();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        let wrapBox = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.wrapBox'));
        console.log(wrapBox);
});
```

But following method returns '*`6 timer(s) still in queue`*' error...

```
it("Should display names",fakeAsync(() => {
        component.names = [
            {
                "firstname": "abc",
                "lastname": "max"
            },
            {
                "firstname": "def",
                "lastname": "max"
            },
        ];
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        let wrapBox = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.wrapBox'));
        console.log(wrapBox);
}));
```

**Note**:

1. The data for array *`names`* is asynchronous since it's retrieved from back end using 'get' operation. But here i'm mocking the data.
2. The data in array is iterated through and passed to another child component which displays it in the view.

Comment: this is a good article to understand https://blog.nrwl.io/controlling-time-with-zone-js-and-fakeasync-f0002dfbf48c

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Thank you for the link! It was worth a read!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those 2 things have nothing in common.

`done` is just a callback to let your test runner know when an async operation is done.

For example:

```
it('should wait for this promise to finish', done => {
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(`I'm the promise result`), 1000)
  );

  p.then(result => {
    // following will display "I'm the promise result" after 1s
    console.log(result);

    // this let your test runner know that it can move forward
    // because we're done here
    // the test will take 1s due to the setTimeout at 1000ms
    done();
  });
});
```

You might also use `async` for that (just to avoid calling `done` manually):

```
it(
  'should wait for this promise to finish',
  async(() => {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve(`I'm the promise result`), 1000)
    );

    p.then(result =>
      // following will display "I'm the promise result" after 1s
      console.log(result)
    );

    // notice that we didn't call `done` here thanks to async
    // which created a special zone from zone.js
    // this test is now aware of pending async operation and will wait
    // for it before passing to the next one
  })
);
```

Now, `fakeAsync` gives you control over time (which is really powerful) so you can write your tests in a synchronous way, and simulate that time goes by to avoid waiting for `setTimeout` for example:

```
it(
  'should wait for this promise to finish',
  fakeAsync(() => {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve(`I'm the promise result`), 1000)
    );

    // simulates time moving forward and executing async tasks
    flush();

    p.then(result =>
      // following will display "I'm the promise result" **instantly**
      console.log(result)
    );

    // notice that we didn't call `done` here has there's no async task pending
  })
);
```

So just to be clear, with `fakeAsync` in the last example, if the setTimeout was set on 10s, the test would still be executed **instantly**.

Comment: also you can add that `done` is a native Jasmine method while `async` and `fakeAsync` are added by Angular testing framework

Comment: Indeed, you'll only be able to use `async` and `fakeAsync` by importing them from `angular/core/testing` :)

Comment: @Maxime Can you give an instance, when each of these scenarios are preferred over others?

Comment: I mostly use async over done callbacks. But I've read that it might be slowering tests down so not sure it's a good idea. About fakeAsync, it's really handy to avoid waiting and taking back control over time, that's just it :)

Comment: Where is tick() mentioned in all of this story?

Comment: Tick is nearly the same as flush. Flush will run all the asynchronous tasks in queue and tick will too if no arguments are provided. But you can also decide to pass a time in ms, and it'll run the tasks that are only supposed to be run during that time. So for example if you have to setTimeout, one at 2s and the other at 1, run tick(1000) and only the first callback will have been called.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a little test that helped me understand what tick can do:

```
it('should tell me what tick can do...', fakeAsync(() => {
    let counter1 = 0;
    let counter2 = 0;
    let intervalTime = 1000;
    let passingTime = intervalTime*5;

    interval(intervalTime).subscribe(() => {
        counter1++;
    });

    setInterval(() => {
        counter2++;
    }, intervalTime);

    expect(counter1).toBe(0);
    expect(counter2).toBe(0);

    let now = new Date().getTime();
    tick(passingTime);
    let later = new Date().getTime();

    expect(now).toBe(later-passingTime)

    expect(counter1).toBe(5);
    expect(counter2).toBe(5);

    discardPeriodicTasks();
}));
```